# Wrong location of controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, picturebox

Here is my code:

```
Dim Offset As Point

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    Offset = New Point(-e.X, -e.Y)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim Pos As Point = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition)
        Pos.Offset(Offset.X, Offset.Y)
        PictureBox1.Location = Pos
    End If
End Sub
```

I am able to do what the user wants, (*drag picture & add button*) although..
**Problem 1**
Whenever I drag the pictureBox inside the panel, it somewhat offsets a little to the right wherever I bring it. Technically, as I move the mouse, the picturebox just moves to the right before following the sequence of the mouse, I know its just minor, but its a bug that I can't let the users to see it.

Hope you guys can help! thank you!

Comment: If you want consultants, then hire some.  This site is for helping you to correct malfunctioning code - not write entirely new code for you.  Problem 1 appears to be on topic.  Please remove Problems 2 and 3.  Also please limit a question to a single issue.  You can post separate questions for each issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the original client location of the picturebox (on mouse down) and do the offset on this point:

```
Private offset As Point
Private pbpos As Point

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    Me.pbpos = Me.PictureBox1.Location
    Me.offset = Control.MousePosition
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then
        Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point((Me.pbpos.X + (Control.MousePosition.X - Me.offset.X)), (Me.pbpos.Y + (Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.offset.Y)))
    End If
End Sub
```